# Is $y(t) = y(t-4)+x(t-4)$ time invariant or not?

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems

I want to check the time invariability of this recursively defined function
$$y(t) = y(t-4)+x(t-4)$$

We can check time invariability of functions expressed in terms of x(t), but I couldn't find anything for such recursively defined function.
In the book *"Signals and System by A. Nagoorkani"*, we can test for time invariance as follow:

> 1. Delay the input signal by m units of time and determine the response of the system for this delayed input signal. Let this
>    response be y1(t).
> 2. Delay the response of the system for unshifted input by m unit of time. Let this delayed response by y2(t).
> 3. Check whether y1(t) = y2(t). If they are equal then the system is time invariant. Otherwise the system is time variant.

Following these steps, the delayed version of input signal is $$x((t-m)-4)$$ But what is its response (y1)? Is it

$$y(t-4) + x((t-m)-4)$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$y((t-m)-4) + x((t-m)-4)?$$

In other cases, we just shift the function $x(t)$ and leave all other terms as it is but the problem here is, the shifting of $x(t)$ may affect the $y(t)$ and so $y(t-4)$ as well. So, should I shift that term as well or keep it as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's re-write your difference equation:
$$y(t) - y(t-4) = x(t-4)$$

- Delaying the input gives the following difference equation for the output $y_1(t)$:$$y_1(t) - y_1(t-4) = x(t-m-4)$$
- A delayed response to an input $x(t)$ gives
  $$y(t-m) - y(t-m-4) = x(t-m-4)$$

From there you can see that $y_1(t)$ and $y(t-m)$ satisfy the same difference equation. The system is therefore indeed time-invariant.